# Is there a 'scratch pad' window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I currently use notepad to store little notes to myself about my code.
This is usually a mixture of code and requirements.

Is there a 'scratch pad' type window in VS where i could do this.

The other alternative is to use code comment blocks in the source files, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode equivalent of Jetbrains/IntelliJ/Rubymine scratches (throwaway notes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147441/vscode-equivalent-of-jetbrains-intellij-rubymine-scratches-throwaway-notes)

Comment: Answers here are quite outdated, while the [proposed] dupe has a 2021 working one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that visual studio has support for git style .md or markdown: [image: Screen shot of Visual Studio with .md file open]

This provides good way of storing notes, requirements and developer instructions such as a readme.

- To use: Just add a file to your solution with a .md extension.

Comment: This requires an extension, available here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaab33c3-437b-4918-8354-872dfe5d1bfe

Answer (score 4):

Try the sticky notes add in

http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/18/VisualStudio2008AddInStickyNotes.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StickyNotes

Comment: Both links are dead now and the addon can't be found in VS marketplace. But found a Scratchpad addon: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidxw888.Scratchpad

Answer (score 3):

On "Solution Level" you can add files (text, html or code) to act as notes files.

Also in projects, you can add files, and set the *Build Action* to *None*.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I'd simply add a .txt file to the solution or abuse comments to do it. However, if you use the scratch pad to store todo lists et cetera you can use TODO: in your comments and visual studio will add them to the built in todo list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Bookmarks" window to scratch some notes regarding different parts of your code:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think Stick notes wont support VS 2005. Anyway WinDBG rocks.