# Window for scratch work in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

(See [Is there a 'scratch pad' window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246295/is-there-a-scratch-pad-window-in-visual-studio-2008) for a similar question about VS2008.)

When I'm working with a project in a text editor, I'm used to opening up a new "anonymous" document window for scratch work, then closing it after I'm done with it. In Visual Studio, creating a new document actually creates a new document at some location. I've been using Notepad for this so far, but I miss the IDE features, and it would seem a bit silly to run Notepad++ right next to VS for this one purpose.

Is there any way to do this from within Visual Studio itself?